# Can I find out what process is generating certificate error popups?

Tags: windows-10, certificate

For the second time I've come into work recently to find hundreds (I can't be sure how many) certificate error popups.  So many that the popup's shadow is black  (See the screenshot).

[image: Certificate error screenshot]

This time it's for *.yourmembership.com Which I don't recognise and don't think I've intentionally visited.  Last time it was for something else but I can't recall.

I am trying to figure out which process or application is generating it.  I have closed one-by-one all my apps to see if they go away in bulk after one particular app closes but with everything closed they are still there.

So is there a way to find out which app or process generated them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Netstat

you could try `netstat -bn` in cmd.exe

*netstat* shows all currently open TCP connections. the `-b` switch names the executable file which created the connection.

For example a simple google search:

```
protocoll    local address    remote address    connection status
TCP    192.168.1.26:35623    172.217.18.174:54690    CONNECTED
[firefox.exe]
```

### Process hacker

another method is [Process hacker](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io) with it you can see which process spawned another.

Comment: Thanks.  If it happens again (I rebooted so they're gone now) I'll try this and see if it will give me any clues.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to determine the process that owns a particular window.

In the UI toolbar, to the right of the binoculars, there's a target/scope icon.  You can drag that onto a window, and when you release the click the Process Explorer UI will highlight the process which owns it.